# python socket , communicate with other computer over the internet without port forwarding

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am creating a program that two computer can communicate with each other over the internet . i created a demo so I could see how would work . This test was on my local network at first , and after i tested so that i can get package outside of the LAN , but i needed to port forward that port . how can I make the program to run as if i port forwarded a port but in reality i didn't go in router to open it . I know for example that video games don't need to in the router to open a port so you could play . My only leads are :
1) work with firewall somehow
2) nat , tcp/udp punch hole
I am new to this and i can't find a good exaple for this

> the code is somthing very basic , just send package to that ip and the reciver confirm it

ive tried to open manualy a port and work . now i need to make it work without opening a port in router

edit : this program should communicate like a peer to peer . the computers send to each other data .

The program is a network of computers that can run code on demand , like how was in 2020 with a program that you could install on your computer and it would run simulation for sciences and research . the client can get ip from a list on the web and it will lissen for data from an ip and afther that it will send it back . the master computer will recieve data and afther that it wil decide what to do with it. this program should be ready to run ought of the box , with no further settings .

Comment: One common solution is to have both clients connect to a server that isn't firewalled, and the server can forward data sent by client A over to client B's TCP connection and vice-versa.

Comment: If you are able to `ssh` into either machine from the other, you can use `ssh` command to set up forwarding. Likewise if both machines can `ssh` into a common third machine.

Comment: @MarkSetchell i don't think so , because the users wouldn't have access to open a port in the router and maybe it won't be opened

Comment: @JeremyFriesner yes , but afther that i would need a direct connection because it could send a lot of data . the program is for my university , i have some professors that are researcher and somethimes they need to do some running/simulation/math thing and we don't have a big computer , but multiple computers and i was thinking if they could utillise thouse

Comment: Once you have a communications path between the two clients through the server, you could use that to orchestrate NAT traversal.  It’s non trivial to implement though, so it might be worthwhile to find a prepackaged implementation rather than rolling your own.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner do you know any library ? i've seen miniupnpc but i couldn't install it because of errors , upnpy i could install but the test code on their site it doesn't work `upnpy.exceptions.IGDError: No IGD found.` error , and natpmp library but i need to read more about it , now it's my only lead